# Send List of Strings from LWC to Apex in batches

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a simple LWC where a user will enter a list of Book titles (on separate lines) into a text area. I then send those books back to apex in a List where I insert the records using the title.

I've been able to successfully insert the list of records, however, if the number of books records is high, I'm getting a "too many SOQL" errors due to other trigger processes happening in the background.

The solution I had in mind was to modify my LWC or Apex so that if a user enters in hundreds of book titles, then only insert a few at a time.

For example:

1. User enters in 500 book titles and clicks "Create Books"
2. Send 50 books back to my apex controller
3. Those 50 books get successfully inserted
4. Continue Steps 2-3 until all books are inserted

**createBooks.html**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <lightning-textarea label="Books:" onchange={handleBookTitles}></lightning-textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <lightning-button label="Create Books" title="Create Books" onclick={handleButton}></lightning-button>
  <div>
</template>
```

**createBooks.js**

```
import { LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import InsertBooks from '@salesforce/apex/BooksController.InsertBooks';

export default class InsertBooksLWC extends LightningElement {

bookTitles;

handleButton() {

    isInserted({ data: JSON.stringify(this.bookTitles) }).then(result => {
        if (result) {
            //books were inserted
        } else {
            //books were NOT inserted
        }


    }).catch(error => {
        //error
    });
}

handleBookTitles(event) {
    this.bookTitles = event.detail.value.split('\n');
}
}
```

**BooksController.cls**

```
public with sharing class BooksController {

@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean isInserted(List<String> books) {

    List<Books__c> booksToInsert = new List<Books__c>();

    for (Books__c b : books){
        booksToInsert.add(b.Title__c);
    }

    if (!booksToInsert.isEmpty()) {
        insert booksToInsert;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe what you have tried and the specific error or problem you have encountered.

Comment: @DavidCheng Done, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try by below JS

Explaination:

1. Store the data in **bookTitles** variable
2. Divide that array into 50 by using [reduce function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)
3. Call backend on each 50 records array.

   ```
   import { LightningElement} from 'lwc';
   import InsertBooks from '@salesforce/apex/BooksController.InsertBooks';
   const PER_CHUNK = 50;
   export default class InsertBooksLWC extends LightningElement {

   bookTitles;

   handleButton() {

   const booksByChunk  = bookTitles.reduce((all,one,i) => {
          const ch = Math.floor(i/PER_CHUNK); 
          all[ch] = [].concat((all[ch]||[]),one); 
          return all
       }, []);

      booksByChunk.forEach((books)=>{
           isInserted({ data: books }).then(result => {
               if (result) {
                   //books were inserted
               } else {
                   //books were NOT inserted
               }
           }).catch(error => {
               //error
           });
       })

   }

       handleBookTitles(event) {
           this.bookTitles = event.detail.value.split('\n');
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has an immense database underlying its platform and this calls for some mechanism to put check on what amount of data processing we can do in a given transaction. It controls and handles all DML operations that are executed from a non-anonymous(apex class) context using internal limits called the **governor limits.**

In cases, where you are not sure, that scale of data you will be processing - it is a good practice to write a batch Apex and configure your apex class to delegate a method that will pass all records(call) to the batch apex for processing.

```
public with sharing class BooksController {

@AuraEnabled
public static void isInserted(List<String> books) {// Delegator, does no other job than sending all the bookNames to batch apex
 

        batchClassNameHere runningbatch= new batchClassNameHere (books);  
        database.executeBatch(runningbatch,200);
 

    

}    
}
```

The batch apex must be composed as a standard Salesforce batch with a constructor to receive the books list!

```
    global class batchClassNameHere Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    private List<String> bookNames;
    private List<Books__c> books;

    public batchClassNameHere (List<String> newbooks) {//parameterized constructor for receiving book names.
        books= new List<String>newbooks;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
      
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<String> bookNames) {
// use the list of bookNames to process your data followed by Database.execute() to run this batch            
    }
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

This is a pattern of programming that can handle any number of records at all times. Thanks.

Comment: Was trying to avoid the batch route, but I appreciate your answer! Although, I may have to revisit this depending on how it goes